save from several tables to one on inkscape
If in a tab I joined several tables when originally there was only 1, how do I save them all so that only 1 large table is made?
i already tried to group them and save but when i put it on a document it dosent shows the whole table

Hi. What do you mean by "if in a tab"?  What kind of tab?  When you say you "put it on a document", what kind of document?  Do you mean in some other software?  Are you saving the SVG, or some other format? Please share a screenshot showing what you made, and what the problem is.
